# Storing user data on web app without authentication

Tags: rest, web

I am curious if there is a way to store user's data without authentication for a web app even when the browser closes etc. From my research so far I am aware of IndexedDB and LocalStorage but I am not sure if this data will be persistent even when the browser closes etc.? I am looking for something that will save the data at least until browser cookies are cleaned.

Comment: Yes, LocalStorage is availabe until the "site data" is cleared

Comment: @nbokmans Thank you! Although, is there a chance the site data can be cleared even when the user doesn't initiate it?

Comment: Not really - the process has to be initiated inside the browser, which usually only the user itself can do. Obviously there's exceptions for malicious browser extensions etc, but I don't think you can do anything about that possibility

Comment: @nbokmans Yup, of course. That's all I needed. Thank you for the information and answer!